# Formatting text that is meant to be replaced

Tags: python, text, replace, formatting, conventions

This is a rather generic question, but I have a textfile that I want to edit using a script.

What are some ways to format text, so that it will visually stand out but still be recognized by my script? 
It works fine when I use text_to_be_replaced, but it is hard to find when you have a large file.

Tried searching, and it seems that the common ways are:

```
%text_to_be_replaced% 
<text_to_be_replaced>
$(text_to_be_replaced)
```

But maybe there is a commonly used/widely accepted way to format text for visibility?

The language the script is written in is python, if that matters... but I'm looking for a more-or-less generic soluting which will work 90% of the time.

Comment: Jinja2 happens to use double curly brackets (`{{ text_to_be_replaced }}`), so that's pretty common I guess.

Comment: I don't know if it's a standard but Jinja2 uses `{{ text_to_be_replaced }}` for rendering HTML templates

Comment: There is no a single accepted format. You just need to pick one you are comfortable with and make sure you handle your special characters (enclosing text to be replaced) properly. You might have a look at python's [templated strings](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html)

Comment: Well, the fact you got two comments saying the same thing within 4 seconds of each other is at least some indication that it would be recognised :)

Comment: @Leiocalyx could you post the script that you are running so that we can see the context you are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought that {{curly braces}} would be fine, but than I went with $ALLCAPS.

First of all, caps really stands out, while lowercase may be confused with the rest of the code.
And while it $REALLYSTANDSOUT, it shouldn't cause any problems, since it's just a "bookmark" in a text file, and will be replaced with the appropriate stuff determined by the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any generic standard here, but if it's meant to be replaced, you can use the new string formatting method as follows:

```
string = 'some text {add_text_here} some more text'
```

Then to replace it when you need to:

```
value = 'formatted'

string = string.format(add_text_here=value)
```

Now print it out:

```
>>> string
'some text formatted some more text'
```

In fact, this quite neat at the addition of curly  `{brackets}` around the text that needs to be replaced also may make it stand out a little.

Comment: Python-side everything is fine, I'm reading from an external text file, making my edits, and writing the result to another (empty) file. 
But as the number of things I need to edit/insert increases, I have to use more and more placeholder words just to mark the exact spot I want the final values to be. And since placement matters, I can't just append.

Comment: So just adding lots of empty `{}` and replacing them is not suitable for what you're after? Because, if you use this method and leave the brackets empty, you can pass in the things you want to replace in positional order, which saves time and is quicker to type